When I am writing dialogue, if the character speaks childishly, would people think I am a bad author?
I am writing a novel right now, so I need some clarification for this.
When writing dialogue about a childish character that will grow and become more mature, will people assume I couldn't write dialogue at the time and got better at it rather than seeing the character's growth?
Also, the changes in personality of the character is marked using changes of fonts.  That technique is also used in showcasing other perspectives within the book.

Do the other characters speak normally? You could throw in other hints at the character's childishness & development to help the reader understand.

Assuming you mean 'dialogue spoken by a childish character' - of course not! It should be obvious to the reader that changes in their speech reflect their growing maturity.

There will be other text around the dialogue of that childish-speaking character: dialogue by other character and, more importantly, narration (of what characters do, what they see, where they are etc.). From that context it will become clear to your readers that you intentionally write that part of the dialogue in that manner, and not because you cannot write better.
I would not use different fonts for different stages of a character's development. This is so uncommon that readers will probably not understand what the different fonts are supposed to mean. You need to express the changes in your character through your writing, that is, with words.

I thought people used different fonts to convey perspective and personality, that’s why I implemented such methods. Thanks for your input!

@AlphaNoodle I'm not saying that it is never done, but in 50 years of reading I have never seen it. But then, I am not familiar with every book that has ever been published. I think it is always a good idea to look at how things are done in the books you like to read. If in those book different fonts are used to convey perspective and personality, and you write the same genre, you can certainly do it, too. But if you rarely or never see it in the genres you read and write, I would avoid it.

I am grateful for your replies and the points made so far. I hadn't seen it either, at least not in the way I did it, though I assumed so. Probably a good idea not to test the limits of literature/bookwriting in my first work. Thank you.
